# Referring nested class in asInstanceOf

Tags: scala, casting, inner-classes, nested-class

I am getting `not found: value Duck`

```
    class Type
    class Value(val t: Type)
    class Duck extends Type {
        class Val extends Value(this)
    }
    def f(individual: Value) = individual.t match {
        // case t: Duck => individual.asInstanceOf[Value] //this is ok
         case t: Duck => individual.asInstanceOf[Duck.Val] //but I need this
    }
```

Adding here some details to improve the question quality. Formal quality checks cannot be wrong. If more letters improves your question, it must be the case. Now, my question is much better and can be posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

```
def f(individual: Value) = individual.t match {
     case t: Duck => individual.asInstanceOf[t.Val] 
}
```

Or this:

```
def f(individual: Value) = individual.t match {
     case t: Duck => individual.asInstanceOf[Duck#Val]
}
```

In Scala, an inner type is defined for each *instance* of the outer class.  So the type you're looking for is `t.Val`, since you have to provide the outer class instance to fully know the inner class type.  If you want to get the super type for all such inner types, you can do `Outer#Inner`.